# Typescript optional type does not allow recursive partial utility type to work

Tags: typescript

I wanted to use the popular `RecursivePartial` utility type to make all fields, objects, and arrays of objects be optional but not invalid. However when a field is already marked as optional, this breaks. It suddenly does not allow partial types. Is there any way to fix this such that `eventA` works like `eventB`?

```
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?:
    T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? RecursivePartial<U>[] :
    T[P] extends object ? RecursivePartial<T[P]> :
    T[P];
};

class MyEvent {
  date!: Date;
  name!: string;
}

interface MyUser {
  name: string;
  eventA?: MyEvent;
  eventB: MyEvent;
}

type PartialUser = RecursivePartial<MyUser>;

const a: PartialUser = {
  eventA: { // It wants all fields defined
    name: '',
  },
  eventB: { // But this one is OK
    name: '',
  },
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIAUCGyw6eANgDwAqAfFALxQDeAUFFANo5ToB2UA1hBAB7AGZQKAXQD8ALhatxHCVAgAPYBG4ATVFAAUPERGRQAqgEo2yqbAQoM2fIWLlTVK1DkLFOZWo3aukIARgBWCMBQNnBIaFi4BESklEo0XgoUSgDcTAC+OUzwJHiougCyIACi2NyRzKxaeBoAhDJQACJNEDms3HgAthCtUKjAyDwA5jm5TEw8GsgiePDQFaaoxozyfYNto+PcU-IQNcAAgrJQFdWawD0qpwBCbden07OgkFBOSSTrm-QYvZ4j8XGQ1htkFQCvAhNxRlA8G1QaR-iZ6PUHrczm1Mb0BhA2gByIkAGnkuXJrBOt2eW28O0JUBJVKglLyOSAA)

---

An attempt at a solution because I still have issues with a field like `users?: User[]`

```
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?:
  T[P] extends (infer U)[] | undefined ? RecursivePartial<U>[] :
  T[P] extends object | undefined ? RecursivePartial<T[P]> :
  Partial<T[P]>;
};
```

It works but I'm trying to understand the consequences of `| undefined`. It seems that it will let me get away with assigning a number to a `Date` for example.. Yikes

---

Attempt 3: I think this works. Just have to do the hard work and add more stronger typechecking

```
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?:
  T[P] extends Date | undefined ? Date :
  T[P] extends (infer U)[] | undefined ? RecursivePartial<U>[] :
  T[P] extends object | undefined ? RecursivePartial<T[P]> :
  Partial<T[P]>;
};
```

Comment: shouldn't the last `T[P]` be `Partial<T[P]>`?

Comment: Oh wow, might just be that simple..

Comment: Hm still doesn't work for a nested array. See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIAUCGyw6eANgDwAqAfFALxQDeAUFFANo5ToB2UA1hBAB7AGZQKAXQD8ALhbiOEqBAAewCNwAmqKAAoeIiMigBVAJRslU2AhQZs+QsXImqlqHNYVFytRu1QQgBGAFYIwFDWcEhoWLgERKSUijSeUI6J5N44ElQA3EwAvgVMPOrIInjw0CaoRozy6JoyUKjAyDwA5gWsyEIkEC1tHdzdRUyl3OWV1VAAothTDayIdWiypmuW40ygkOkEeAC2OvTRdnEZzmQLGsBUE-BC3G1QYIcnLY7Hp8tQq0ZUC02PJWAwuM0oAByJpQqCFeQSIpAA)

Comment: Also a simple fix - https://tsplay.dev/WG4PXw

Comment: ^ Allows Date to be anything..

Comment: How can I add a hard rule like `T[P] isa Date ?` instead of `extends`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the type of the `eventA` field is actually `MyEvent | undefined`. Since it includes the union with `undefined`, it will no longer match to the `extends object` clause and thus is mapped back to itself (`T[P]` in the final case).

One way to fix this is to reform your `RecursivePartial` so that each type conditional happens on the overall type rather than on the keys of the type. This way the type can distribute itself over each part of a union separately.

Eg:

```
type RecursivePartial<T> =
  T extends Date ? T :                                       // Leave Date objects alone
  // Also of note: possibly add cases for Set, Map, other JS builtins...
  T extends (infer U)[] ? RecursivePartial<U>[] :            // Recurse into array types!
  T extends {} ? {[P in keyof T]?: RecursivePartial<T[P]>} : // Recurse into object types!
  T;                                                         // Leave other types as-is.
```

This seems to produce the inference you are looking for:

```
const a: PartialUser = {
  eventA: {   // No Error!
    name: '',
  },
  eventB: {
    name: '',
  },
};
```

Let me know if this still doesn't work for your actual use case.

---

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIAUCGyw6eANgDwAqAfFALwBQUUFUEAHsBAHYAmqUAETycoAfmZQAXIwntOvfgAp0XAGYRkUAKoBKANoBdMbAQoM2fIWLktVQ1Jks53PlADeAX2Nu9OKCqgAawgQAHtVZgNRSRMkNCxcAiJSSl8DKi9pJgoAbnp6eBI8VH4AWRAAUWwuYHcZHmEIAEIYoU48pi48AFtmmNRgZBUAczyPfJVOZFU8eGhyrVQNOs6eiH7BkY7WauAAQWiocqruYG2IXYAhGOPdsfzQSChLZJJF5dpYswSX6zIFpbIKh5AqhLgDKB4GK-UjvTSfNwyC6nPYxRFMVa9GIAcmxABoZB4CUxkTVrisMV0sVBccSoET6B48kA)

Comment: With this implementation, every method of the `Date` object can be undefined

Comment: This did work but so does @geoffrey's one liner

Comment: Actually this lets me do weird things like assign a number to a date.

Comment: I don't think there is a way around that generally. Either you recurse into all objects and make their fields optional... or you don't. In that regard a `Date` is just like any other object. You can add exclusions for specific cases (like `Date`) but there is no way to do this (afaik) in the general case.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the case for `Date` but also of note would be cases for the built in JS `Map` and `Set` objects, and perhaps some others.